# How to insert entire page content into CF7 form submission?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I would like the entire page contents (text only) to be included when someone fills out the form.

(This is for a contract, and I want to keep the record of their agreement bound together with the actual text they agreed to in one place).

Is this possible with CF7? Can the email I get contain the page's text alongside the user's email, name, etc.? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

you can do one thing create a page your contract and in contact form 7 add a checkbox with requeried filed , if and add your validation text(like , if you check this box you agree with contract ) and link with contract page.
that's it.